# Responsive site to Joomla template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, joomla-template

I have a question about converting existing web-site to a Joomla web-site.

Currently, I'm in charge of editing and posting content on a site for non-profit student association. The site is hosted on a server from one of our members and we're editing the HTML when we need to change something, basically duplicate/rewrite when we need to. Summed up - everything is done manually, there's no CMS which is pretty lousy solution.

This was only a temporary solution, so we're getting free hosting these days, and we were told that their server enables us use of Cpanel and Joomla 3.6.4. I have user accounts and passwords, tried to log in and look around for a bit.

Main goal is to keep the design and the feel of current web-site, but to update the content more often (blog posts, news etc.) 
Page is currently used only to display basic informations, contact and some pictures. The site is responsive and is based on a template which is HTML5, CSS 3, Bootstrap 3.X compatible, and the template had examples of blog page, news page, contact with Google Map, ... - elements which new page should have. There's no need for user login, e-store, comparisons or such things.

The site is currently down for unknown reason, so I can't link to it, but it's pretty similar to this [template](https://themeforest.net/item/attyia-creative-ngo-and-charity-html5-template/13152572), basically it has the same elements (so, currently using only home page, about us, team, no store, blog and events).

I would like to know if it's possible to convert such page to Joomla 3.6.4 template by editing code in Notepad++ or something similar, and if yes, where can I find information or tutorials how to do that?

I searched for the basic and advanced [tutorials](https://docs.joomla.org/Main_Page), but I'm not sure it will work, mainly all tutorials are for static pages. If it's not possible to create .ZIP file with template installation, is it possible to use current code (CSS, PHP, JS...) to create layouts or whatever is that called in Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly use Joomla by installing a template similar to the existing website and then using a custom CSS file to refine the styling. Content would need to be copied and pasted into articles or similar. In practice, it is usually easiest to paste as plain text and then reapply formatting as necessary.

There might be a simpler solution where you can convert your static website to a CMS using [Sitecake](http://sitecake.com/) or similar. Sitecake is a "Simple CMS For Static Websites".